# What artsy/museumy/culturalish stuff is there to do in Indianapolis?

Tags: usa, museums, indiana, indianapolis

I am currently residing in Indy and may not be here for a huge amount longer. That being said, I am a huge fan of museums and the like but feel like I've more or less seen all there is for me to see, which basically consists of the following:

- The Kurt Vonnegut Library
- Fountain Square (not really a "museum" type place, but more of a funky little community that hasn't appeared to have changed in 50 years)
- The Indiana Historical Museum on Canal Walk
- Victory Field (because I like baseball)

Is there anything else that is particularly educational, informative, and so on that I'm missing? I'm not expecting the Metropolitan Museum of Art here but perhaps there is some sort of equivalent of my home town's (Seattle) Museum of History and Industry? I don't believe that much happened regarding the Civil War this far north outside of recruiting and (if memory serves) one incursion by Morgan's Raiders (which ultimately bypassed the city anyway). Perhaps there's a district with preserved older buildings the way Martin Luther King's birthplace is set up in Atlanta?

I guess there's the Indianapolis Motor Speedway but I'm not a big racing fan. If there's enough good history stuff I would probably be okay with it, though (for instance, I'm also not exactly a Coke connoisseur but I still enjoyed the Coke Museum in Atlanta for the history/branding exhibits). Any suggestions/questions/examples would be awesomer than awesome, thanks.

Comment: What type of museums are you looking for?

Comment: [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Indianapolis) lists fourteen museums and twelve sights to see.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Wikitravel. I'm asking if any of them are any good.

Comment: @Karlson: I am a big history buff, but I'm down with science and the like as well. I know there is a renowned children's museum, but since I am a single guy that's not the kind of experience that I'm after.

Comment: @JohnCraven "any good" is a very subjective question to ask and is likely to be closed as not constructive. ([Please see the FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help)).  If you're looking for Met, MoMA, Guggenheim, you won't be able to find them in Indianapolis (sorry!).  So what kind of experience are you after?

Comment: Thanks. I've added some more detail to my initial question. Let me know if that's enough.

Comment: I have changed the title and made up 3 brand new words in doing so. I have an English degree, it grants me the leeway to do this.

Comment: Do you have car access? Like planes? There's a huge aviation museum at Wright-Patterson AFB near Dayton (2 hrs away).

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikivoyage there is quite a bit to do in [Indianapolis](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Indianapolis#Do) -- from the last time I was in the city (which was not recently), I remember the First Friday open galleries being a lot of fun, as was the Melody Inn.

Comment: It's recommended on SE sites that you include the information in your answer, in case the linked website changes / disappears.  If you could summarise the content on the Wikivoyage Do section, that'd make it a great answer.